# Kivy button to display a random number as text

Tags: python, button, kivy, radbuttontextbox

I'm new to the kivy world and struggling to find the solution for this problem I'm facing.

I am trying to create an "APP" that once open displays a button with a randomly generated number (in python). The number should be already there as the "text" of the button.

On_release, this number get stored in a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

.py - This code is what I have so far

class FirstPage(Screen):
random_num = ObjectProperty(None)

```
def random_number(self):
    value = random.randint(1,1000)

    self.random_num.text == value
    ln_db.add_number(self.random_num.text)

    self.reset()
    sm.current = "main"

    def reset(self):
        self.lucky_num.text = ""

    def logOut(self):
        sm.current = "login"
```

.kv

:
name: "first"
random_num: random_num

```
FloatLayout:

    Label:
        pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
        size_hint:0.8, 0.2
        text: "This is your Lucky Number!"

    TextInput:
        id: random_num
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.4 , "top":0.5}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2

    RoundedButton:
        pos_hint:{"x": 0.3 , "top":0.4}
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        text: ""
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            app.root.current = "number"
```